# Is it better to use class selectors or custom attribute selectors with jquery?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have read that it is better to select using "id" than "class" with jquery. However, say i have several divs on a page that i need to select with jquery and perform the same manipulation. I cannot select with the "id" attribute because it would nolonger be unique. eg:

```
<div id="selectMeOnClick">
    ...
</div>
<div id="selectMeOnClick">
    ...
</div>
... many more divs ...
```

which leaves me (i think?) with 2 alternatives:

Use class selectors

```
<div class="selectMeOnClick">
    ...
</div>
```

Use custom attribute selectors

```
<div data-select="selectMeOnClick">
    ...
</div>
```

My question is: Are these really the 2 alternatives left? And what is the most efficient solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use class selectors. Using custom attribute selectors would be:

1. **Invalid HTML**. HTML only permits certain named attributes to be present on certain types of elements.
2. **Slower**. While jQuery can use native `.getElementsByClassName` in your first snippet, it can't for the second. This could lead to a slowdown in modern browsers.

Comment: As for #1... The OPs example is perfectly valid in HTML 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As the comment above says, it is valid as of html 5 so that's not a concern for me. As with #2: I imagined that to be the case. Is this a fact that it is slower? If so i will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @YakobeYak - Whether or not the selection is slow will depend on the browser. The first thing jQuery tries when selecting is the browser's native `querySelectorAll`. If it exists, and the selector is valid, it will be very fast.

Comment: @Yak: I would assume `getElementsByClassName` to be faster in browsers that support it.  However, many browsers also support `querySelectorAll`, including IE 8, which doesn't support `getElementsByClassName` and requires a slower, non-native implementation.  I'd certainly be interested in seeing some benchmarks.

Comment: To add some reference to my and @Andy's comment, [here's a compatibility list](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13) of browsers that support `querySelectorAll`. As you can see, it is widely supported in modern browsers.

Comment: I guess this means that we are unsure whether it is faster selecting by class or by custom attribute? I only wondered if the attribute would be faster because an attribute has only one value while a tag may have many classes in the class attribute.

Comment: @YankobeYak: I did a performance test using jQuery. http://jsperf.com/attribute-versus-class-selector The class selector, for each browser, is faster than the attribute selector (by a few percent). In IE though, there is a difference of over 20%.

Comment: actually running these tests now in firefox gives pretty equal results, with custom attribute being slightly faster most of the times, while in chrome it is about 40%(sic!) slower, and in vivaldi about 30% (and vivaldis class seletor is about 15% slower than chromes for some reason), interesting how things like these change over time

Comment: and running r24 firefox makes custom attribute 66% slower while for chrome it is 75%

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is better to use "id" than "class" with jquery. But not only with jquery. This is general approach.

In your situation you have to provide more information. If you want to select several divs with same class  - may be all of them are child of other div, e.t.c. And you can get them as a child of some div which you can get by id.

You have to create such DOM structure that you can access to elements by id or logically by some properties.

Also, if you want to change some css attribute in exact css-class, it is not the worst idea to get div's by class.

Also custom attribute selections not good way. It is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is the fastest in JavaScript. Because there is only one element for sure (if your code is valid). The class and the custom attr are going to be the same speed I think.

I don't like using custom attributes because it's not valid and it makes the DOM pretty messy. I prefer using `.data()` to store data that are relative to the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple selection like this performance wont be a problem. but if your `div's` are within a container with a Id, for example

```
<div id="Main">
    <div class="selectMeOnClick">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="selectMeOnClick">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**: according to [gdoron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601179/gdoron) comment

Then the fastest selector would be `$('#Main selectMeonClick')`

Comment: It doesn't need to construct a new jQuery object.

Comment: Point taken, I don't see that as a huge cost, but you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use both depending on the occasion. If for example a row in the table represents some data that I want to have laying around but not necessairly display I use custom attributes. Sometimes it's just so nice to write stufflike this:

```
$("input[action=do-something]").click(function() { ... });
```

and not be forced to mess around with element classes. I realize it is a bit slower but taking into account that it happens only once after the page is loaded I can live with that.